# Virtual Machine stalls after migration

Tags: ubuntu, migration, linux-kvm

I have Ubuntu VMs running on an Ubuntu server Host. When moving a VM from one host to the other using `virsh migrate --live` some of the VMs stall out. The only way to get them back is to kill them and reboot. I can't find any information about this. Has anyone experienced this and found the problem or a solution?

Edit: It seems like the machines giving me problems have full or almost full boot partitions. This is not always the case, but could this have anything to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

[This bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libvirt/+bug/1001625) explains the problem I am having and offers an excellent solution.

The problem stems from a bug in the pc-0.12 machine type, which has experienced many bugs. The developers have recognized this and made it easy to convert from pc-0.12 to the new pc-1.0 machine type.

The [libvirt-migrate-qemu-machinetype](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/libvirt-migrate-qemu-machinetype.1.html) utility can be used to migrate the machine type, it should be installed already if you have been keeping up with updates.

Here's how to convert a vm to the newer machine type.

1. Shut down VM.
2. Change the machine type `libvirt-migrate-qemu-machinetype -o pc-0.12 -t pc-1.0 <domain>`
3. Check that this worked `virsh dumpxl <domain> | grep -i machine`
4. Start machine `virsh start .
5. Try a migration.

I tested this with a machine that always caused me trouble. Performed a migration before converting and it froze.

After changing the machine type, I was able to migrate it multiple times without a problem.